# Why is my variational auto-encoder generating random noise?

Tags: autoencoders, pytorch, variational-autoencoder

This is my first variational autoencoder. Background info: I am using the MNIST digits dataset. The model is created and trained in PyTorch. The model is able to get a reasonably low loss, but the images that it generates are just random noise. Here are my script and the images that were generated by the model: https://github.com/jweir136/PyTorch-Variational-Autoencoder-Latent-Space-Visualization.

Any advice or answers on how to solve this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! There's a reference implementation for the VAE in PyTorch: [https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/vae](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/vae). Maybe you should compare it with your implementation.